# Generate Angular form from JSON

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I want to generate an Angular 6 reactive from JSON at runtime. I also need field level actions like if it is dropdown than I can perform `onchange` event and for other fields also we need the same function. I have searched the net but not able to find out the solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at [this](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) example from the Angular docs (it shows pretty much exactly what you want)?

Comment: I have tried with 'https://medium.com/@mail.bahurudeen/create-a-dynamic-form-with-configurable-fields-and-validations-using-angular-6-994db56834da' link.. and able to generate the form..but the issue is that I am able to call some custom event from button or any other field...

Comment: This question is rather brief and came with no explanations after requests for clarity were made. I will try to put it on hold for now.

Answer (score 0):

let's say this is your json data,

```
data= {name:'name',adress:'some data'}
```

then, you can do like this

```
 constructor(private fb:FormBuilder){}

 ngOnInit() {samplefb=this.fb.group(userForm:this.fb.group({}));
 //after getting data i mean,service.getdata().toPromise().then(your code)

 (<FormGroup>this.samplefb.get('userForm')).addControl('name',this.fb.control(data.name));
 (<FormGroup>this.samplefb.get('userForm')).addControl('address',this.fb.control(data.address));


  }
```

hope that would work!

Answer (score -1):

Use `ngFor` and `ngIf` to iterate of the JSON and display the correct fields.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div *ngIf="item.type === 'dropdown'">...</div>
    <div *ngIf="item.type === 'otherType'"> </div>
</div>
```

For more information, follow these links:

[NgForOf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

[NgIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

Comment: Not really what he's looking for imo. He wants to "convert" JSON data into an Angular Form.

Comment: @Zooly: If that is the case I apologize, but for me it is unclear with the given information.

Comment: @Zooly: Given his new comment he is trying to do exactly what I posted.